# Как напечатать дробное число такое как 2/7 в Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести на экран дробное число?
Например, 2/7

Comment: Эм, `print('2/7')` ?

Comment: [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html) различные форматы для вывода формул поддерживает (ascii, unicode, latex, etc). В [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/) можно как текст так и объекты красиво печатать. .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> x = Fraction(2,7)
>>> x
Fraction(2, 7)
>>> print x
2/7
>>>
>>> x += Fraction(3,5)
>>> print x
31/35
>>>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.